# Is it "Noetherianess" or "Noetherianity"?

Tags: terminology

I wonder what the correct noun for the adjective "Noetherian" is. Should I say

"By Noetherianess of $R$, the ideal $I\subseteq R$ can be generated by finitely many elements." or

"By Noetherianity of $R$, the ideal $I\subseteq R$ can be generated by finitely many elements."?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: ["-ness"](https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Applying_Noetherianness) seems to be proper suffix. On the other hand, ["-ity"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/noetherianity) may also be valid.

Comment: In similarly to "evenness," it should be "Noetherianness" with two n's.

Comment: English is not really a language of strict rules, specially when building nouns and verbs. My personal taste likes "Noetherianity" better.

Comment: Noetherianess would be an archaic term for a woman Noetherian ring. :)

Comment: "Because the ring $R$ is Noetherian, ...."

Comment: I had to write something like this in a formal paper this week, and my cop-out solution was to write the equivalent of, "By the Noetherian condition on $R\dots$"

Comment: But, to get back to the "evenness" example, I barely even see evenness used by real mathematicians. And I think saying "By the Noetherian property, .the ideal .." without specifying $R$ here. Noetherianness and Noetherianity are both terrible.

Comment: For example, M.SE has only 349 pages that use evenness as a word. Compared to >200K that use the word "even." And some of those use "evenness" for an informal measure of the degree that a distribution is uniform, rather than any binary notion of even/odd.